# angular-datatables payload format does not change upon subsequent calls to reloadData()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

After the initial load of data into the table using angular-datatables ([Homepage](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)), I intend to change the time span for which to reload and display data. The span is selected using two datetime input fields. However, all subsequent requests do not modify the time window parameter in the `dtOptions` obeject.

The strange thing is that, when I console.log the modified `dtOptions` object, the changes seem to take effect, that is - data property of `dtOptions` reflects the newly selected time range. The inspection of the request in the "Network" tab of "Developer Tools" in Chrome, shows that the old time range values are still used, which causes no updates to the table entries.

---

Example:

This is the `{from, to}` value I get in the "Network" tab of the "Developers Tools" whenever I POST for new data:

```
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)                     Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
->from:1412172055200
->to:1412690455222
```

While it's equivalent in the "Console" tab, when issuing `console.log($scope.dtOptions);` actually reflects the time range I pre-selected.

```
Object {ajax: Object, reload: true, integrateBootstrap: false, hasColVis: false, hasColReorder: false…}
    ajax: Object
        data: Object
            ->from: 1412518000453
            ->to: 1412690800493
            __proto__: Object
            datatype: "json"
            type: "POST"
```

I tried a number of ways to update/rewrite the `from` and `to` values in the payload prior to calling `$scope.dtOptions.reloadData()`: wrote to `$scope.dtOptions.ajax.from` directly, tried passing an updated `payload` object, and the latest attempt (code below to give an idea) - used `newOptions()` to create the `dtOptions` object anew.

```
var payload = {
                from: tFrom,
                to: tTo
            };

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('ajax', {
                    url: constantCfg.apiEndpoint+constantCfg.uri.usersStats,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: payload
                });

$scope.dtOptions.reloadData();
console.log($scope.dtOptions); <- causes 'Console' tab output discussed above
```

All ways, do update the values of payload, when printed in the "Console" tab, but requests in the "Network" tab still indicate the usage of the old time range values.

None of the ways I tried to update `payload` object caused no additional warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you need to define the `ajax.data` as a function and define your parameters to send to the server.

```
var from = 1412518000453,
    to = 1412690800493;
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
         url: constantCfg.apiEndpoint+constantCfg.uri.usersStats,
         type: 'GET',
         data: function(d) {
             d.from= from;
             d.to = to;
         }
     });
$scope.reloadData = function() {
    // Compute your from/to variables
    from = 1412518000463;
    to = 1412690800593;
    $scope.dtOptions.reloadData();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this might be it:

```
$scope.changeOptions = function() {
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(2)
        .withDOM('pitrfl');
};
```

From: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/changeOptions

In other words, you need to create a new dtOptions, dtColumns or dtColumnDefs. Databinding in Angular takes care of the updating.

Comment: Nope, tried that just now. When I don't use the `reloadData()`, no call to the back end occurs at all. This [example](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/dataReloadWithAjax) shows an equivalent of the operation I carry out. I think that the example you specified might be valid without an AJAX call...

Comment: Sad, have you tried updating using $scope.dtOptions.withDataProp(newToFrom)?

Comment: I just tried doing `$scope.dtOptions.withDataProp(payload);  $scope.dtOptions.reloadData();`, and can see the `sAjaxDataProp: Object` property set with the new/updated values of `from/to`, however the `Form Data` field in the "Network" tab is still holding the old time range values. PS: Thank you very much for these suggestions.